# How can I learn actual type argument of an generic class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a parameterized class :

```
class ParameterizedClass<T extends AbstractSomething> {
}
```

calling:

```
new ParameterizedClass<Something>();
```

So how can I get actual type Something of `T` by using Java Generics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done, but [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure) can make it very hard. As the other answers discuss, you either have to make a subclass of `ParameterizedClass` or add a field of type `T` to `ParameterizedClass`, and the reflection code you need to do it is convoluted.

What I recommend in these circumstances, is to work around the issue like this:

```
class ParameterizedClass<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    /** Factory method */
    public static <T> ParameterizedClass<T> of(Class<T> type) {
        return new ParameterizedClass<T>(type);
    }

    /** Private constructor; use the factory method instead */
    private ParameterizedClass(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Do something useful with type
}
```

Due to Java's type inference for static methods, you can construct your class without too much extra boilerplate:

```
ParameterizedClass<Something> foo = ParameterizedClass.of(Something.class);
```

That way, your `ParameterizedClass` is fully generic and type-safe, and you still have access to the class object.

**EDIT**: Addressed the comment

Comment: It ***IS*** possible. This answer is wrong. Check the other answer which has the solution.

Comment: @AdamArold I didn't know it yet at the time I wrote the answer, but you're right. I still don't recommend it, though. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You could use this trick in your constructor: (see http://www.hibernate.org/328.html)

```
Class<T> parameterType = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

But I believe this code only works when the class is sub-classed and an instance of the sub-class executes it.

Comment: I know this trick and am using on DAO classes. But this is not what I'm looking. To use this trick, I guess, we have to define actual value of generic type of parent class on sourcecode. 

GenericDAO<T extends Model>

UserDAO extends GenericDAO<User>

Answer (score 3):

If you mean just from the object itself, you can't. *Type erasure* means that information is lost.

If you have a *field* which uses the parameterized type with a concrete type argument though, *that* information is preserved.

See [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html), and particularly the [section on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3).

Answer (score 0):

This is a mostly problematic topic, since it only works under certain conditions like expected (expecially in complex scenarios).

But Xebia published a [good article](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/12/a-general-purpose-utility-to-retrieve-java-generic-type-values/) on the whole thing.