# How to check that a method returns Collection<Foo> in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I wish to a check if a method exists in an interface based on its signatures.

The signature that the method should have is:

```
Collection<Foo> methodName(Spam arg0, Eggs arg1, ...)
```

I can find the methods via `Class.getMethods()` 
then find the name, parameters and return type respectively with `method.getName()`,  `method.getParameterTypes()` and `method.getReturnType()`.

But what do I compare the return type to in order to ensure that only methods that return `Collection<Foo>` are chosen, and not other collections?

```
method.getReturnType().equals(Collection.class)
```

Since the above will be true for all methods that return a collection, not just for those that return a `Foo` Collection.

Comment: See http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520057/how-can-i-learn-actual-type-argument-of-an-generic-class

Comment: This isn't a duplicate - the question is how to inspect the parameterized return type, not instantiate an instance of the parameterized type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a method named `public Type getGenericReturnType()` which can return (if it's the case) a [`ParameterizedType`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).

A [`ParameterizedType`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) can give you more informations on a generic type such as `Collection<Foo>`.

In particular with the `getActualTypeArguments()` method you can get the actual type for each parameter.

Here, `ParameterizedType` represents Collection and `getActualTypeArguments()` represents an array containing Foo

You can try this to list the parameters of your generic type :

```
Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
if (returnType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
    Type[] typeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();
    for (Type typeArgument : typeArguments) {
        Class typeArgClass = (Class) typeArgument;
        System.out.println("typeArgClass = " + typeArgClass);
    }
}
```

**Sources :**
[http://tutorials.jenkov.com/](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html)

Comment: Thanks Colin. That did it and the article explains a little bit more about how and why.

Comment: I'm wondering, would [method.getTypeParameters()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericDeclaration.html) work too?

Comment: Method.getTypeParameters() give generic informations on the method itself for example Collections.unmodifiableList :
`public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) {` The result will be an array containing "T"

Answer (score 2):

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html

Answer (score 0):

Generic type parameters are not retained at runtime (i.e. it's a compile-time only feature) in Java so you cannot do this.